# Report Manager hyperlinks pointing to wrong address

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, reportmanager

I'm helping our SA migrate a reporting service instance to a new server and we're encountering a strange issue. She installed SSRS 2005 and restored the reporting services databases without any issues. She then restore the encryption key from the previous server without a problem.

But when we try to open report manager, it goes to the URL of our previous SSRS instance instead of the new one (i.e. when going to https://[new URL]/reports, it takes us to https://[old URL]/reports/pages/folder.aspx). The only way we can get to the current reporting service instance is by specifying the entire URL (i.e. https://[new URL]/reports/pages/folder.aspx). Also, when hovering over the links at the top (i.e. Home, Site Settings, etc), the hyperlinks also point to the old URL. I imagine this doesn't have anything to do with the database we restored, so we're wondering if this has something to do with the encryption key from the old server.

Sorry if this isn't clear, but any input is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, did the reporting services hostname change?

Comment: Oh crap sorry I used angle brackets in some of my sample URL's. Fixing now. But yes, we're hosting reporting services on a different domain.

Comment: Have you checked your target server URL SolutionExplorer>Project>Properties.

Comment: It's not the report deployment location that's the problem, it's the URL's within the Report Manager. Even though it's hosted on the new server (www.newwebsite.com/reports), all the URL's within the Report Manager are still pointed to the old instance (www.oldwebsite.com/reports).

Comment: Did you look through the settings in RS Config?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is going back in time but we had the exact same problem. Testing my memory, I believe the server name is stored in the `Keys` table in the `ReportServer` database in the column `MachineName`. That will be your old server name.

1. Take a backup!
2. Change it to your new server name.
3. Restart the Reporting Services service.